# XSLT: how to get already populated tag value in new computation

Tags: xslt, xpath

My xslt has the following form, an excerpt:

```
 <xsl:variable name="nameValue">
  <name>
    <xsl:call-template name="process-Value">
      <xsl:with-param name="value" select="./address/name"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  <name>
 </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:if test="message and ( $nameValue = 'John' || $nameValue = 'Cena')"
```

> Here I am trying to get the previously computed value of ***name***, and
>   based on the value name tag i.e the content inside the name tag, I am populating the
>   ***message*** tag
>   The above condition is showing error in my Eclipse.

```
   <message>
      <xsl:value-of select="message"
   </message>
  </xsl:if>
```

**Result**

```
<category> 
  <name>Bablo</name>
 </category>
 <category>
  <name>John</name>
  <message>St. John</message>
</category>
<category>
  <name>Cena</name>
  <message>Fighter</message>
</category>
<category>
   <name>Jill</name>
</category>
```

> So if the name is either 'John' or 'Cena' then only the "category" tag
>   is holding the "message" tag  but in the case the value of "name" tag
>   content is 'Bablo', the "message" node is not at all attached into the
>   "category" tag.

My problem is can I do this? If not this way what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use? If you want to refer to that `name` element you create "above" the `xsl:if` then you need to put that into an `xsl:variable` (and in the case of XSLT 1 you would furthermore then need to use `exsl:node-set` or similar to convert the variable of type result tree fragment to a node set if you want to select nodes with XPath).

Comment: I am using XSLT 2.0 version.Please elaborate more on your answer. I am new to this XSLT.

Comment: Consider to show us what type of result that called template returns, I am not sure you need an element wrapper like that `name` element at all if you want a simple string value comparison later.

Comment: I have edited my question, If its not clear let me know I will do further modification.